# "Setting initial password for current user and oneadmin FAILED"

Tags: opennebula

Please, I am installing Minione, Openneubla on Ubuntu on my machine, but I encounter a problem each time at the step "Setting initial password for the current user and oneadmin FAILED." Can someone help me, please?

```
chmod +x minione 
./minione --force
```